# How to group same multiple window functions as one and call by an alias wherever needed in the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, window

How can I address the issue of having the same window function multiple times in a single SQL query for different aggregations? Is there any way I can alias it and call it multiple times as needed in the query.

I tried using 'Window' clause for the same but SQL Server currently doesn't support the 'Window' clause.

```
select empid, qty, 
       sum(qty) over (partition by empid order by month rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as running_sum, 
       avg(qty) over (partition by empid order by month rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as running_avg, 
       min(qty) over (partition by empid order by month rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as running_min, 
       max(qty) over (partition by empid order by month rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as running_max
from employee
```

Is there a way to remove the redundancy in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Not in SQL Server,  ANSI SQL supports a `WINDOWS` clause for defining windows which can be re-used.  However, SQL Server does not support it.

I think you can slightly simplify your logic:

```
select empid, qty, 
       sum(qty) over (partition by empid order by month) as running_sum, 
       avg(qty) over (partition by empid order by month) as running_avg, 
       min(qty) over (partition by empid order by month) as running_min, 
       max(qty) over (partition by empid order by month) as running_max
from employee;
```